# How Can I Convert That Piece of Matlab Code to Java?

Tags: java, matlab

I have a piece of Matlab code but could not find out how to convert to a Java code. What does this row mean? How can be converted to Java?

Matlab code:

```
b = all(x <= y) && any(x<y);
```

Hint: x = [1,2,3,4,5], y = [5,4,3,2,1]
What is b as the result?

Comment: You can just run it in MATLAB (or [GNU Octave](www.gnu.org) which has the same syntax) to see what the result is. Apart from that, `all`, `any`, `&&`, `<=`, and `<` are all standard logical operators that mean the same in almost any language.

Comment: @Adriaan thank you adriaan, I tried them in online octavia compiler, but could not understan well, I still could not implement the all and any operations in Java:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Java Streams like in

```java
var x = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var y = new int[] {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
var b =    IntStream.range(0, x.length).allMatch(i -> x[i] <= y[i])
        && IntStream.range(0, x.length).anyMatch(i -> x[i] <  y[i]);
```

<sup>not handling `x` and `y` having different sizes!</sup>

Answer (score 0):

From the matlab official site:

*A <= B returns a logical array with elements set to logical 1 (true) where A is less than or equal to B; otherwise, the element is logical 0 (false).*

Up to this you have 11100 in the first comparison.

*B = all(A) tests along the first array dimension of A whose size does not equal 1, and determines if the elements are all nonzero or logical 1 (true). In practice, all is a natural extension of the logical AND operator.*

So `all(x <= y)` must return 0.

*B = any(A) tests along the first array dimension of A whose size does not equal 1, and determines if any element is a nonzero number or logical 1 (true). In practice, any is a natural extension of the logical OR operator.*

So `any(x < y)` should be 1.

`&&` is `AND`

The rest is up to you